# What is this called in php: ->

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicates:**
> [In, PHP, what is the “->” operator called and how do you say it when reading code out loud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588149/in-php-what-is-the-operator-called-and-how-do-you-say-it-when-reading-code)

I use it all the time, it's impossible to search for. What is the technical name for it?

like `$object->property`

UPDATE: I see now that someone asked this question before, but when you search for something like "php ->" you don't get good results.

Comment: Is it not a pointer, as used in C since an array is a list of references to actual objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580757/what-is-the-official-name-of-cs-arrow-operator

Comment: [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: @mario that is a nice reference.

Comment: @pfunc: I've just stolen that link. It's one of the links in the [|faq|](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=faq&pagesize=50) tab for the `php` questions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply enough, it's called the [arrow operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

ETA:

As others have mentioned, the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) also calls this token the "object operator".  So, the docs aren't entirely self consistent, which I suppose is true of any real world documentation.

Comment: +1 for referencing its mention in documentation

Comment: that linked to "Static Keyword" not arrow operator

Comment: And btw the `class::method` operator is called the Scope Resolution Operator 
http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Comment: @pfunc - yes, but if you look at the 4th sentence on the page, you'll see it mention how "Static properties cannot be accessed through the object using the arrow operator ->"

Comment: Actually, it's called the [`Object Operator`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) as defined in the token list (`T_OBJECT_OPERATOR`)...

Comment: @ircmaxell - So the `::` would be called the `PAAMAYIM NEKUDOTAYIM` then as well? :)

Comment: The definition is the same for C++.  Leave it to standards committees and documentation writers to make an official name that tells you absolutely nothing about how it's used.  If you don't know it through some other means, you won't get any hints from the name. :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580757/what-is-the-official-name-of-cs-arrow-operator/1580778#1580778

Comment: @Eric: Yes. I'm not arguing if we should be using the token names or not, but I was just pointing out the alternative name as defined by PHP itself (not the documentation).

Comment: I agree with ircmaxell, this is normally referred to as the object operator. The arrow operator is more appropriate as a short form of the double arrow operator (the one used for hash declarations and foreach loops with key).

Comment: @ircmaxell - agreed, just giving you a hard time.  The documentation isn't entirely consistent on this one (as tends to be true of all real world documentation).

Comment: @marc - it's call the scope resolution operator because nobody can pronounce PAAMAYIM NEKUDOTAYIM ;)

Comment: +1 to @John: Knowing that it is called the 'arrow operator' doesn't help with knowing what it's function is within PHP.

Comment: -1 for snatching unrighteous rep. all reputation gained from duplicated question should be nulled.

Answer (score 8):

It's also known as `T_OBJECT_OPERATOR` in the tokenizer/parser http://de3.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php

Answer (score 5):

The member access operator. Sometimes called the single arrow operator or the dereference operator.

Answer (score 1):

This is called "dereference" in most languages, I suspect its the same thing in PHP.

Comment: I think you me "dereference"? It's not really the same thing as the traditional dereference operator in languages with explicit pointers (such as C's `*`).

Comment: I completely agree with you, Amber.