# What's the official name of '.' and '->' operators in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, operators

Im curious if they have an official name or just 'dot' and 'arrow'? I try search this in cpluscplus and in Deitel, but didn't find anything

Comment: "Partial" duplicate, which actualy answers the full question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580757/what-is-the-official-name-of-cs-arrow-operator

Comment: In the index of the C Standard they are indexed as "dot operator" and "arrow operator."

Comment: Yeah... when actually speaking I call them "dot" and "point".  "arrow", while fine in print, is too much of a mouthful for normal conversation:)

Comment: _@HanArantes_ You should note that c and c++ have each their own standards and _official_ documentation.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: There are alternative names in the standard

Comment: There is no language C/C++. Each has its own naming conventions. Which one do you use?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  i thought the name in both was the same, but in this case, lets the question still the same, even to know whats (if there's any..) the difference between then

Comment: @HanArantes It appears to be the same (from comments and answers) in this particular case, but that won't work in general for C and C++ language semantics or terminology questions.

Comment: @HanArantes That's not how this works. “Give me an overview over the names in more than one language” is too broad for this format. Ask about one language at a time.

Comment: @HanArantes : The objection to the term "C/C++" is a reflexive action amongst some, it is legitimate when referring to a product such as "*Microsoft C/C++*" (a name briefly used for v7 of Microsoft's compiler before "Visual C++") or "*C/C++ Users Journal*" (a now sadly defunct print magazine), but if you are referring to the languages C and C++, it is best to separate them (as I have done in the edit) to avoid the flaming.  Sometimes it is legitimate to ask a question covering both languages, but best to be careful to avoid distracting comment noise (apologies Olaf)..

Comment: @FUZxxl : Really?  While C and C++ are somewhat diverging in standardisation, they share a common root, common library subset, direct interoperability, and more often that not are implemented in the same toolchain.  It is often legitimate to ask a question referring to both languages.  The "crime" (and a minor one, that some get far too exercised about IMO), is in referring to them as a single language.

Comment: @Clifford I'm slightly sick of discussing this topic. Point is, to answer a “both C and C++” question, you have to be an expert in both and let's face it, too few people are that. Asking an overly broad questions (like one about both C and C++) attracts poor answers or answers that do not really answer the question. That's why Stack Overflow closes questions as “too broad” in the first place.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it really should be seeking the answer in one language.

Comment: @FUZxxl : I take your point, but would rather take each question on its merit that apply a blanket policy.  Sometimes a question is just not so objectionable as to be worth punitive closure, which is how some SO users seem to apply it.  I say let it lie, and its "quality" will be duly reflected in its voting.  All that said, I am not sure that the question serves much of a useful purpose to the community - I'm certainly not up-voting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C standard calls them *member access operators*, but only in the index. They aren't given a name anywhere else except the one place in the index. In the same place, the `->` operator is called *arrow operator,* the `.` operator is called *structure/union member operator.*

Comment: The index uses the term "arrow operator" more often. And the `.` is the _structure/union member operator_.

Comment: @Olaf I haven't found that one in the standard on the first search, but now I do, that's funny.

Comment: I also first found only the name `structure/union pointer operator`, but that is not very descriptive and very unintuitively. Personally, I prefer "arrow" and "dot" "operator" when talking, just because it's a bit complicated to speak in symbols.

Answer (score 1):

According to my [preferred (C++) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) they are called [**Member Access**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_member_access_operators) operators.

But to distinguish one from the other these are usually called *dot* and *arrow* operator (see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580757/what-is-the-official-name-of-cs-arrow-operator) @AnT mentioned in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36206315/whats-the-name-of-and-operators-in-c/36206357#comment60045891_36206315)).

Comment: That's a C++ reference by the way.

Comment: I think he is asking for the names of the individual operators, not the name of the set to which they belong.

Comment: The index of the C reference has index entries for "arrow operator (`->`)"  and "dot operator (`.`)". It also has index entries for "`->` (structure/union pointer operator)" and "`.` (structure/union member operator)". So "arrow operator" and "structure/union pointer operator" are synonymous, as are "dot operator" and "structure/union member operator".